# How to do load test using JMeter when the login is with MFA

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to do load test using JMeter. The issue is that I get login after MFA (Multi-factor authentication).

It always shows the result status with no success.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of MFA is to forbid automation, so in few words, it's impossible.

You should disable it to performance test the underlying application.

Comment: The purpose of MFA is to enhance security, not to prevent automation. You're thinking of CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 0):

I faced several times this problem that can have many faces and solutions.
Basically you get down to:
enter a dynamic PIN, or
enter some serial ID, or
sign some token.
The last two are simple, as you can ask your customer/system owner to give you the data and do the task (e.g. get a set of test certificate to sign the tokens, or a set of test ID).
In case of dynamic PIN, you can ask the system owner to set a range of user with fixed PIN (this require a code modification) or to provide you a library that dynamically generates correct PINs (the same they use to generate the PIN they send via SMS).
The latest is the best solution but requires a very high trust.